# Ember.js - Nothing handled the action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm following the Railscats on Ember.js and got the following error when trying to execute the action 'addEntry'

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'addEntry'. If you did
>   handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an
>   action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

Here is my code:

***application.handlebars***

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Raffler</h1>
    {{input type="text" value=newEntryName action="addEntry"}}
    <p>{{newEntryName}}</p>
    <ul>
        {{#each entries}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**application_controller.js.coffee**

```
Raffler.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
    entries: []

    addEntry: ->
        @entries.pushObject name: @get('newEntryName')
        @set('newEntryName', '')
```

Comment: Try using this line: `Raffler.EntriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In old versions of ember.js, the action helper used any method in the controller object as an action. But in the new versions you have to put any action in the `actions` hash. So update your controller to the following:

```
Raffler.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  entries: []
  actions:
    addEntry: ->
      @entries.pushObject name: @get('newEntryName')
      @set('newEntryName', '')
```